# How to unsuspend VM in VMware sdk?

Tags: java, api, vmware

What is the opposite function to suspend in VMware?
I am using VI Java API for simplification.

Comment: Don't you see something called Resume?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but there is no Resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently PowerOn is the Resume in VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

You can power on VM using VI java SDK by following command.

```
virtualMachine.powerOnVM_Task(hostSystem);
```